problem installing bazel for drake on ubuntu
After running sudo ./setup/ubuntu/install_prereqs.sh, I get this error on completion:
/tmp/bazelisk_1.22.0-amd64.deb: OK

(Reading database ... 352591 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack /tmp/bazelisk_1.22.0-amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bazelisk (1.22.0) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/bazelisk_1.22.0-amd64.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bazel', which is also in package bazel-bootstrap 3.5.1+ds-3ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/bazelisk_1.22.0-amd64.deb
The Drake source distribution prerequisite setup script has experienced an error on line 20 while running the command source "${BASH_SOURCE%/*}/source_distribution/install_prereqs.sh" "${source_distribution_args[@]}"
I am using a ubuntun 22.04.5 LTS
the bazel version details is:
Build label: 3.5.1- (@non-git)
Build target: bazel-out/k8-dbg/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Sun Aug 15 22:54:48 2021 (1629068088)
Build timestamp: 1629068088
Build timestamp as int: 1629068088

I haven't found a solution on the Drake publications on GitHub, what is the cause of the issue?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Yes, the bazelisk package that Drake is trying to install is not compatible with bazel-bootstrap package from Ubuntu.  If possible, uninstall bazel-bootstrap before running install_prereqs.
Or, run install_prereqs --without-bazel to skip that part.  A CMake install (cmake && make install) still works fine without installing bazelisk.
